# NavMeshAgent jittering

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, navmesh

NavMeshAgent character jitters while we both move same direction.
And Same as croshair also Jitters.

```
public class AiLocomotion : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerController player;
    public float maxTime = 1.0f;
    public float maxDistance = 1.0f;    
   
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator anim;
    float timer = 0.0f;

    

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        player = FindAnyObjectByType<PlayerController>();
        
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer < 0.0f)
        {
            float sqrDistance = (player.transform.position - agent.destination).sqrMagnitude;
            if (sqrDistance > maxDistance * maxDistance)
            {              
                agent.destination = player.transform.position;        
                
            }
            timer = maxTime;
        }
        
        anim.SetFloat("speed", agent.velocity.magnitude);
    }

    
}
```

```
public class Cross : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float offset;
    public float distance;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(target.position, target.forward, out RaycastHit hit, distance))
            transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);
        else    
            transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position + (target.forward * offset));
    }
}
```

[Video Link](https://youtu.be/2o-JMAQAKhc)

I am traying to create an enemy character that follows player but when we move same direction enemy jitters. Also A crosshair for my character Jitters. I made researches but could not find a proper solution.
I found this solution :
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxfaHwp3yEg)
It was okay but I could not use timer with this solution, it is not working with float timer.

Could anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that the camera is jittering, a common issue. Put your camera controller logic in LateUpdate() or use [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) to delay it even further. It appears to me that the Agent moves smoothly when the camera is still and that also the stationary objects jitter.

You can also stop the camera movement and see if anything changes.

If this is not helping then maybe you have to post more of your code.

Comment: Camera iş workink with cinemachine. And it as arranged to Lateupdate

Comment: Try changing Update Method. For me 
Update Method: Smart Update
Blend Update Method: Late Update works the best, and about cursor glitching you want to move updating its position to Update. This is view thing, so you want it up to date EVERY frame not only when physics update.

Comment: I am very sure that it is not your navmesh code, you even set the destination at most every second. The Navmesh agent moves from itself. So none of the code that we see should result in jittering.

I'd make the camera stationary and compare the result and see if there is still jittering involved or not.
And you should enable vsync for these kind of tests and make sure that the editor game window has it enabled.